# _corrupt_record Column in Databricks Yields NULL Values When Using JSON Schema (PySpark)

Tags: json, pyspark, null, databricks, corrupt

I'm consuming a REST API in Databricks using PySpark. The API response returns a list where each element of the list is a JSON string. When I parallelize the JSON, it yields a **_corrupt_record** column where each value of that column is a JSON string:

```
### API Call
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=api_call_header)
api_json = response.json()
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(api_json))
display(df)
```

This is what the JSON string of a single value looks like when I copy it into a JSON validator:

```
{
    'Var1': 'String',
    'Var2': {
        'Var3': 'String',
        'Var4': None,
        'Var5': 'String',
        'Var6': 'String',
        'Var7': 'String',
        'Var8': 'String'
    },
    'Var9': None,
    'Var10': 'String'
}
```

For whatever reason, I can't access the nested Struct objects of Var2. When I use the **from_json** function and the following from-scratch schema, it yields NULL values from Var2 onward:

```
schema = StructType([
     StructField('Var1', StringType()),
     StructField('Var2', 
       StructType([
         StructField('Var3', StringType()),
         StructField('Var4', NullType()),
         StructField('Var5', StringType()),
         StructField('Var6', StringType()),
         StructField('Var7', StringType()),
         StructField('Var8', StringType())
       ])
     ),
     StructField('Var9', NullType()),
     StructField('Var10', StringType())
])
```

This is my code attempting to parse the JSON string:
`df = df.withColumn('struct_json', from_json(col('_corrupt_record'), schema))`

That parses the first key:value pair but yields the rest of the column values as NULL:

```
*object:*
    Var1: "String"
    Var2: NULL
    Var3: NULL
    Var4: NULL
    Var5: NULL
    Var6: NULL
    Var7: NULL
    Var8: NULL
    Var9: NULL
    Var10: NULL
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Attempted Solutions:**

1. **JSON Schema from Scratch -** As mentioned above, it yields NULL values.
2. **multiLine=True and allowSingleQuotes=True Read Options -** Found this in another StackOverflow post but it still yielded NULL values when using my from-scratch JSON schema.
3. **JSON Schema Using rdd.map Method -** I tried to derive a schema using `json_schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row._corrupt_record)).schema` but that simply created a one-layer Struct object where the layer consisted of the entire JSON string without any nested objects parsed out.
4. **SQL to Parse Key:Value Pairs -** Too many nested objects and arrays to successfully parse and yielded too poor performance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**The answer to this was embarrassingly simple:**

From the API call, `api_json = response.json()` creates a Python dictionary. This was confirmed doing `type(api_json)`.

Creating a DataFrame using the `spark.read.json` method was incorrect since the source `api_json` data was a dictionary not a JSON.

So the fix was changing this:

```
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=api_call_header)
api_json = response.json()
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(api_json))
display(df)
```

To this:

```
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=api_call_header)
api_json = response.json()
df = spark.createDataFrame(api_json, schema=schema)
display(df)
```

For the schema, I used the one I had built from scratch in PySpark.